# Solution for ISP blocked gaming ports

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, nat, cloud

I wanted to play a Ubisoft's for Honor on my pc. But NAT type strict is bothering me a lot. If my NAT is strict I can only connect to NAT type open players. Which takes forever for me to get into a group.

I've tried port forwarding my router as well but that didn't work. I guess the problem is at my ISP. ISP is blocking my ports. I contacted him and am still waiting to listen from him.

I was wondering if I can tunnel my connection through available ports. The ports I want are TCP: 13000-13005 ,14000-24 and 13200 UDP- 3075. I can also rent a cloud system to tunnel my connections. But I want to know is it possible.

Comment: Yes but my current guess would rather be that your forward isn't working or your system firewall is interfering.

Comment: seth 11 sure ,you can assume that ,If its only that my port forwarding isn't working then I would be happy to reslove that issue , I would send details about my home network as soon as possible

Comment: If you are beind your ISP's NAT then you will be unable to forward ports.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that the ISP blocks that many ports. Probably you need to open/forward those ports in your fw/modem/router and then you should be fine. TCPs do not even need actual forwarding so you should only open the UDP and you will most likely be able to play just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that your ISP is blocking your ports. However you might have made a mistake in portforwarding your router. Keep in mind that it might take a while for portforwarding changes to take effect and maybe in your case a router restart.

There could also be different things that stop you from having NAT type open. Make sure to check the following things.

1. Turn off windows firewall it might limit your connection
2. Turn off the firewall from your Anti-virus
3. Wait a little while after portforwarding and test it with
   (http://www.canyouseeme.org/) to see if you ports are actually open
4. Make sure you are using the right computer IP to forward the ports
   to (just incase)

Answer (score 0):

Check the WAN IP address on your modem and what IP you see on the internet Whois websites e.g. [whatismyip](https://www.whatismyip.com/). If they are different, your ISP NAT your WAN (External) IP to another IP and you need to ask them to not do that.

Some ISP like [Northland vyvebroadband](https://vyvebroadband.com/) charge $5 per month for this.

Answer (score -1):

I did port forward successfully ,But no avail , Finally my problem did resolve partially when I used vpn ,by doing so my nat type reduced to moderate type. The vpn I am using is paid for one month ,my next aim is to use amazon cloud vpn and I speculate that it will surely make it NAT type open. Otherwise, NAT type moderate also reduces match making time in ForHonor... Thank you all for stating  your  thoughts ..